# Can I use Google Colab to process some data and return the result to my program?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, cloud, google-colaboratory

I'm building a program which does Sentiment Analysis on a piece of text. I want the user to download the program onto their computer to be able to use it. However, installing AI model libraries onto every computer is unnecessary and would require large download spaces. Is there a way for me to create a Google Colab notebook and have the program run that Colab notebook and then return the result onto the program?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.